# building a box a bit special

Tags: tables, boxes

I'm trying to build in latex this box:

[image]

I have been trying with this code:

```
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
 \enc{cyan}{ NOMBRE }&\enc{cyan}{ $\text{1}^{\text{er}}$ APELLIDO } & \enc{cyan}{ $\text{2}^{\text{do}}$ APELLIDO } & \enc{cyan}{ CARN\'{E}/C\'{E}DULA } \\
  \hspace{4cm} & \hspace{4cm} & \hspace{4cm} & \hspace{5cm} \rule[10pt]{0pt}{12pt}\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.25cm}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
 \enc{cyan}{ CENTRO UNIVERSITARIO }&\enc{cyan}{ GRUPO} & \enc{cyan}{FECHA } \\
  \hspace{8cm} & \hspace{4cm} & \hspace{5cm} \rule[10pt]{0pt}{12pt} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{0.25cm}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
 \enc{cyan}{ NOMBRE DEL PROFESOR QUE APLICA EL EXAMEN}&\enc{cyan}{FIRMA } \\
   \hspace{13cm} &  \hspace{4.1cm}  \rule[10pt]{0pt}{12pt}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

But, actually, this is not a "box", and I have problems with the vertical lines (it has not the same place).
I thought to use the command `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}  \end{tabular}` but with this code I can not use an exactly hspace (I think).

What can I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the “code” button (with “{}” on it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8}
NOMBRE & 1 APELLIDO & 2 APELLIDO & CARNE/CEDULA\\
\hline
&&&\\[1em]
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{CENTRO UNIVERSITARIO} & GRUPO & FECHA\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & & \\[1em]
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.8}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{NOMBRE DEL PROFESSOR QUE APLICA EL EXAMEN} & FIRMA\\\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & \\[1em]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

If you want the columns to be of equal width you could change the row `&&&\\[1em]` to

```
\hspace*{3cm}&\hspace*{3cm}&\hspace*{3cm}&\hspace*{3cm}\\[1em]
```

You can also play with the height `1em` and the color and so on.